# Release CUDA/GPU resources in python ipython notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

Currently I am running into an issue where I can't use my GPU in an ipython notebook because it permanently locks up resources(Memory Exhausted Error) while the notebook runs.  I think this is usually a fine situation, but does a method exist to release the resources of the GPU in python/tensorflow?

Thanks